# Error: Time-out interval must be less than 2^32-2. Parameter name: dueTm

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I have a one-to-many relationship within my class model.

Example:
A single role can have many permissions attached to it. so have two table one from the role and one for the permissions for each role.

Now i have a role class which in turn has a permission list as a member of that class. When i need to do an update, i instantiate a `transactionscope` object, and do an update for the role. After that is done and with the `transactionscope` still open, i open another `transactionscope` for each permission in the list and close it immediately after the update has been done.

The update for the role works just fine

But, now the problem is that when it tries to instantiate a transactionscope for the first permission on the list it trows an error saying:

```
Error: Time-out interval must be less than 2^32-2. Parameter name: dueTm
```

Comment: I believe the question is about .NET Framework Transactions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx Possibly in relation to ADO.NET and/or SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution.

Scenario:
I have two base classes for my Business Layer, `BaseBLL` and `BaseListBLL`. Each of these classes provided a method that calls an astract method that must be implemented in you concrete class. These classes started a `TransactionScope` before handing off to the abstract class to perform tasks like update or insert.

Note: After the BaseListBLL starts off a `TransactionScope` it calls the method in the `BaseBLL` that also starts it's own transaction. This is because, we'll be inserting or updating a list of classes derived from the `BaseBLL` which all together are contained in a class derived from `BaseListBLL`.

Now for example if we are to update a role in the roles table only one transaction would be started. But now the complexity comes when we have a role object having another class that derives directly from the `BaseListBLL`.

A transaction would be started for the list first and another for each `BaseBLL` object in the list to do all the insert or update.

So now, after the first insert, the error:

```
Error: Time-out interval must be less than 2^32-2. Parameter name: dueTm
```

is thrown.

What i did was

For the list class, i set the `TranscationScope` object this way:

```
TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)
```

and for the other class

```
TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TimeSpan.MaxValue)
```

The conclusion i have derived is that the error is being thrown because i was using the same transaction created by the `BaseBLL` derived class from the list. I had to suppress the ambient transaction when it was time to do an update of the list of items.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and the answer to this is simple and is found [in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7863f7e5-ec86-4f77-90e2-dc212ff099a2/got-this-error-timeout-interval-must-be-less-than-2322?forum=windowstransactionsprogramming).

What's happening is that the outer `TransactionScope` and the inner `TransactionScope` have a **Timeout mismatch**.  The inner `TransactionScope` is trying to set itself as something greater than the outer `TransactionScope`.

How does this happen?  The answer is that we were setting the Timeout to be equal to `TimeSpan.MaxValue`...BUT...the limit for this is actually `TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout`.  So when the inner `TransactionScope` sets the timeout it blows up because it is a value greater than the outer `TransactionScope`.

**This caused problems when nesting transactions:**

```
public static TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope()
        {
            var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
            };

            return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions);
        }
```

**This works fine when nesting transactions:**

```
public static TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope()
        {
            var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions
            {
                IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
                Timeout = TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout
            };

            return new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions);
        }
```

The person who answered claims this is a known bug.  In my opinion the fix would simply be to 'fail fast' and throw an exception if the Timeout is set to a value greater than `TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout` instead of throwing an exception if the inner `TransactionScope` tries to set a value greater than the outer `TransactionScope`.

Answer (score 0):

The source code of the class `System.Transactions.TransactionScope` shows that it will create a `System.Threading.Timer` instance in some situations. The timer requires that `dueTime.TotalMilliseconds` should not be greater than `0xfffffffeL`, but the value passed to dueTime is `TimeSpan.MaxValue` (`0x7fffffffffffffffL` in ticks, namely, `0x346DC5D638865` in milliseconds). That's why the exception is thrown.

So I think the better solution is to give the `TransactionScope` a smaller timeout.