# In SQL What is the default max transaction timeout

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, transactions, timeout

What is the default value in the machine.config for `maxTimeout` (see example) if no "system.transactions" element is present on the machine.config?

```
<system.transactions>
   <machineSettings maxTimeout="??:??:??" />
</system.transactions>
```

I'm asking this because the code is crashing due the following exception and it seems that it's related to the transaction exceeding a timeout, it is crashing during the `SaveChanges` method and the exception that I'm receiving is the following:

```
The transaction associated with the current connection has completed
but has not been disposed. The transaction must be disposed before
the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.
```

This is the piece of code that is crashing:

```
using (TransactionScope transaction = TransactionHelper.CreateTransactionScope())
{
    using (EFContext efDBContext = new EFContext())
    {
        try
        {
            efDBContext.Connection.Open();  

            foreach (MyEntity currentEntity in myEntities)
            {
                //Insertion
            }

            transaction.Complete();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Inspect current entity
            //Get Total Time of the run
            //Number of entities processed
        }
        finally
        {
            if (esfDBContext.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                esfDBContext.Connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I create the `TransactionScope`:

```
public static TransactionScope CreateTransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption option = TransactionScopeOption.Required, IsolationLevel isolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
{
    var transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions()
    {
        Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue,
        IsolationLevel = isolationLevel
    };

    return new TransactionScope(option, transactionOptions);
}
```

Comment: Almost no-one seems to know about this, but you need to be very careful. Your machine.config always takes precedence: http://blog.muonlab.com/2011/08/03/net-4-transactionscope-timeout-is-ignored-if-greater-than-machine-config-maxtimeout-setting/ - "...if you provide a timeout greater than the machine.config value, [the runtime] ignores it and uses the machine.config one. Silently. No complaining, no warning."

Comment: Here is very good answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1367630/1267128

Comment: When creating the `TransactionScope` with maximum timeout, consider using `TransactionManager.MaximumTimeout` instead of `TimeSpan.MaxValue` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21935333/7665486)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Default = 10 minutes. Max = [Infinity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.configuration.machinesettingssection.maxtimeout.aspx)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.configuration.machinesettingssection.maxtimeout.aspx

Answer (score 9):

There is not a server side time-out is MS SQL.

It is always the client that throws an exception after a set duration.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2005/10/20/483015.aspx

You are really wanting to look at the command time-out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

The default here is 30 seconds.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't catch your comment, the Transaction douration is configured in the server in a couple of places, "machine.config" being the most important, "app.config" and at the code level, if using the code, it will ignore app.config, BUT if it exceeds it seems it is using the TransactionManager.DefaultTimeout, which seems to be 1 minute, i'm NOT sure about this, but i'm trying to confirm that.

Comment: typically there is the command time-out on SQL and the page timeout in .NET. What is the actual exception being thrown?

Comment: The transaction associated with the current connection has completed but has not been disposed.  The transaction must be disposed before the connection can be used to execute SQL statements.

Comment: it sounds like you are not cleaning up the objects and closing the connection. Can you paste the code in the question and i can debug?

Comment: See the code above, i'm wrapping all my calls within using statements, that should not be a problem.