# azure custom apis: performing database transaction returns a timeout

Tags: javascript, azure, transactions

On a azure custom api, I'm attempting to perform bulk insert operation to three tables utilising database transctions.Then I'm facing this error on the console.

> The request 'POST /api/saveinvite' has timed out. This could be caused by a script that fails to write to the response, or otherwise fails to return from an asynchronous call in a timely manner.

```
exports.post = function (request, response) {

console.log("save invite executed!!");
var jsonfriendcircle = request.body.jsonfriendcircle;
var jsoninviteelist = request.body.jsoninviteelist;
var jsoninviteefriendcirclelist = request.body.jsoninviteefriendcirclelist;
console.log("Circle is :" + jsonfriendcircle);
console.log("Inviteelist is :" + jsoninviteelist);
console.log("Inviteefriendcirclelist is :" + jsoninviteefriendcirclelist);
var parsedjsfrcircle = JSON.parse(jsonfriendcircle);

var mssql = request.service.mssql;
console.log("mssql obj :" + mssql);

mssql.open({
    success: function (connection) {
        console.log("connection to db success");
        console.log("circle id: " + parsedjsfrcircle["id"]);
        console.log("circle name :" + parsedjsfrcircle["circle_name"]);

        var sqlst1 = 'insert into friendcircle (id,circle_name)values(?,?)';
        connection.query(sqlst1, [parsedjsfrcircle["id"], parsedjsfrcircle["circle_name"]], function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error:" + err);
                connection.rollback();
                response.send(statusCodes.Error, { message: '' });
                connection.close();
                return;
            } else {
                // connection.commit();
               // connection.close();
            }

        });



    }
    , error: function (err) {
        console.log("Unable to connect to DB :" + err);
        response.send(statusCodes.Error, { message: err });
    }
});

};
```

Comment: code is too long to read, but let me try some guess. have you try to just save some dummy data with this bulk insert?

Comment: @XiaominWu yes, i wanted to do a bulk insert transaction using mssql.open()

Comment: so if it works when saving small trunk of data in batch, i guess the real data you are saving is too large that cause timeout? try to look for any setting that increase timeout windows maybe?

Comment: @KumaranathFernando did you try closing connection at the end? Once it has checked all the connections.

Comment: I see some problems with your code:
1. You respond to the request on every sql execution. 
2. You commit on every insert ( How is this in a single transaction ? )
3. You fire all queries at once, thus you might be using all of your available sql connections
Suggestions:
1. use promises and wait for all to be executed
2. use an orm, avoid writing sql by hand. (if there is no orm available, only then you compose a single sql query from all the data you want to insert)
3. Respond only once
4. break your code into smaller, self-descriptive functions

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like your trying to do too much.  Inserting a few hundred rows should come back before the timeout.
**You'll get a timeout if there is permissions issues** with the Mobile Services user on the database table and your transaction and custom error handling may be hiding that.  Ensure you've run a

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE ON OBJECT::[dbo].[Invitee_FriendCircle] TO [Created_MobileServicesLogin_User] 
--For whatever name was created when you made the app (not the name you entered when you created the app, but the wacky one that mobile services made)
```

Some things to try:
Ensure the tables you are inserting to are indexed for the type of insert you're doing.  If it's a huge table and indexing is an issue, let the mobile api insert to a small temp table and then run an asynch job with sp_start_job to update the main table with the temp table.  That way you are not waiting while the table does the update.

Write stored procedures in the database that contain the inserts and pass the variables into them instead of writing the INSERT query here.  Inside the sproc you can also do BULK INSERT if you really are passing a lot of values and need to do it quick.

Modify the ConnectionTimeout property in the connection string to your database.
You can modify the request.service.config.sqlConnectionString.

Try stripping it down to find the problem.  Remove the transaction and just try doing it without the transaction and custom error handlers, on just one table at a time.  Try

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
var jsonfriendcircle=request.body.jsonfriendcircle;
var jsoninviteelist=request.body.jsoninviteelist;
var jsoninviteefriendcirclelist=request.body.jsoninviteefriendcirclelist;
var mssql=request.service.mssql; 

var sqlst1='insert into FriendCircle (id,circle_name)values(?,?)' ;
mssql.query(sqlst1,[jsonfriendcircle.id,jsonfriendcircle.circle_name], {
        success: function(results) {
             response.send(statusCodes.OK, { message : 'success' });
        },
        error: function(err) {
           console.log("error is: " + err);
        }
    });   
};
```

Try them one at a time to see if anything fails, and if it does, check the LOGS on the Azure portal to see if it was a permission issue.

Good Luck!

Comment: This accounts to some useful information !!Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm new to azure mobile services, could tell me where grant query is executed? Is it on another custom api?

Comment: You would have to execute it on the database side.  Use SMS and log into your database with your admin account.  Find the LOGIN that Mobile Services created under ServerName/Security/Logins. You **won't** find it under DatabaseName/Security/Users.   It will be long and have a bunch of random characters.  Then run the GRANT command on the particular database in the server.

Comment: I updated the my code with a single insert without database trasaction, but still I get the timeout! what could be the reason?

Comment: From the old Azure Portal (manage.windowsazure.com), click on Mobile Services icon, click on the name of your mobile service, and then click the word "LOGS" on the top.  If the database throws an error it's actually not logged here as a red "error" like a timeout is, but as "informational" notice.  But the first word in the text of the "message" column is usually "error: ....".  What is showing up in your Logs?  It's usually something more than just the timeout.  On the "Configure" page in the Mobile Service on the azure portal, is the database and server listed there still good?

Comment: I traced the error, the timeout was due to unwritten response.I had to send back a response, using request.respond()

Answer (score 0):

Probably a transaction timeout after 30 seconds?
[In SQL What is the default max transaction timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915462/in-sql-what-is-the-default-max-transaction-timeout)

Try to rewrite the insert into multiple smaller transactions